# How can I escape a string in classic ASP for use in XPath query?

Tags: c#, xpath, asp-classic

I have string I'd like to escape for use in an XPath query.  In C# I am able to do this using a call to `SecurityElement.Escape`.  Is there an equivalent call in classic ASP?

Comment: Rob, can you provide more context.  Executing an XPath against an `MSXML.DOMDocument` will not work using the accepted answer.  Hence you must be doing something else.

Comment: Sorry yes it did work if I change the xml to contain the escape versions of text.  More specifically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148884/why-is-the-proper-xpath-query-to-find-the-value-in-this-xml-document is the problem I was encountering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you'll need to deal with string escape yourself.

```
xpath = "//node[@attribute='" & SecurityElementEscape(value) & "']"

Function SecurityElementEscape(value)
    SecurityElementEscape = 
        Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(value, 
            "&" , "&amp;" ), '' // must be first one
            "<" , "&lt;"  ),
            ">" , "&gt;"  ), 
            """", "&quot;"), 
            "'" , "&apos;") 
End Function
```

Comment: Damn.  Thought I might have to do that.  Thanks.

Comment: I should be surprised if escaping to `&apos;` etc. worked, since this are XML entities that have no meaning in XPath.

Comment: @Tomalak:  +1 Yes I'm surprised that Rob has found this to work.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: It (`//node[@attribute='bla &apos; bla'`) *would* work, if the XML goes like `<node attribute="bla &amp;apos; bla" />` ;-)

Comment: My mistake: first version I was escaping `'` but so I came across http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape.aspx and changed this code without proper testing