# What is the proper XPath query to find the value in this XML document?

Tags: xpath

Suppose I have this XML document...

```
<root>
  <str name="My node's attribute">My string's value</str>
</root>
```

I want to get the value of the "str" element based on a known value of the elements "name" attribute so I use the following XPath query...

```
str[@name='My node's attribute']
```

But that doesn't work for me at least not in classic ASP and C# because of the single quote which of course conflicts with the single quotes used in XPath syntax.  An exception is thrown in both cases.

What is a possible solution here if I have the restriction that I can't change the XML document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use " in the xpath instead:-

C#

```
 string xpath = "str[@name=\"My node's attribute\"]";
```

VBScript

```
 Dim xpath : xpath = "str[@name=""My node's attribute""]"
```

Comment: Or C# `string xpath = @"str[@name=""My node's attribute""]";`

Comment: The VBScript version worked for me.  Thanks alot!  C# is returning nothing for me though.  I would imagine C# works for you fine Anthony?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
str[@name='My node''s attribute']
```

Comment: Doubling up the ' character is not an escape sequence understood by XPath.

Answer (score 0):

```
str[@name='My node&apos;s attribute']
```

Comment: In raw XPath as executed against an XmlDocument the XML entities are not understood.  In XSL it will be unescaped before the XPath is parsed resulting in the same problem.